# Errors scraping a specific part of an Amazon table using xpaths

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to scrape some data from amazon item pages. My code is fairly simple:

```
def getAsinData(asin, proxy):
    url = 'https://www.amazon.com/dp/' + asin

    s = HTMLSession()
    r = s.get(url, proxies={'http://': proxy, 'https://': proxy}, timeout=2)
    r.html.render(sleep=1)

    product = {
        'title': r.html.xpath('//*[@id="productTitle"]', first=True).text,
        'price': r.html.xpath('//*[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]', first=True).text,
        'details': r.html.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[8]/div[22]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/span/span[1]', first=True).text
    }

    print(product)
    return(product)
```

The problem is with when I try to scrape this specific part of the page:
[Amazon Item Rank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnB3M.jpg)

Because I am using xpaths I can't seem to simply copy and paste it's location because it does not have an ID or text. It returns this error:

```
File "c:\scrape.py", line 37, in getAsinData        
    'details': r.html.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[8]/div[22]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr[6]/td/span/span[1]', first=True).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

So I tried going up the levels of the HTML until I found a div with an ID of prodDetails which I am using to grab the whole table that can be seen in the image. The problem is that it returns the whole table obviously:

```
'details': 'Product information\nPackage Dimensions\n18.7 x 4.7 x 4.5 inches\nItem Weight\n2.05 pounds\nManufacture/2 Inch Thick Kitchen Floor Mats, Holiday Gather 18" x 30"', 'price': '$26.99', 'details': 'Product information\nPackage Dimensions\n17.1 x 4.r\nSoHome\nASIN\nB089HPSSZF\nCustomer Reviews\n/* * Fix for UDP-1061. Average customer reviews hn/* * Fix for UDP-1061. Average customer reviews has a small extra line on hover * https://omni-grok.amazon.com/xref/src/appgroup/websiteTemplas a small extra line on hover * https://omni-grok.amazon.com/xref/src/appgroup/websiteTemplates */ .noUnderline a:hover { text-decoration: none; }\n4.7 out of 5 stars 44 ratings P.when(\'A\', \'ready\').execute(function(A) { A.declarativ/retail/SoftlinesDetailPageAssets/udp-intl-lock/src/legacy.css?indexName=WebsiteTemplates#40 */ w.ue) { ue.count("acrLinkClickCount", (ue.count("acrLinkClickCount") || 0) + 1); } }); }); P.when(\'A\', \'cf\').execute(function(A) { A.decla
.noUnderline a:hover { text-decoration: none; }\n4.2 out of 5 stars 23 ratings P.when(\'A\', \'r{ if(window.ue) { ue.count("acrStarsLinkWithPopoverClickCount", (ue.count("acrStarsLinkWithPopoverClickCount") || 0) + 1); } }); });\n\n4.7 oueady\').execute(function(A) { A.declarative(\'acrLink-click-metrics\', \'click\', { "allowLinkDe#144 in Floor Comfort Mats\n\nDate First Available\nJune 1, 2020\nWarranty & Support\nProduct Warranty: For warranty information about this prfault" : true }, function(event){ if(window.ue) { ue.count("acrLinkClickCount", (ue.count("acrLinkClickCount") || 0) + 1); } }); }); P.when(\'A\', \'cf\').execute(function(A) { A.declarative(\/2 Inch Thick Kitchen Floor Mats, Damask Grey 18" x 30"', 'price': '$26.99', 'details': 'Product information\nPackage Dimensions\n18.7 x 4.7 x'acrStarsLink-click-metrics\', \'click\', { "allowLinkDefault" : true }, function(event){ if(winn/* * Fix for UDP-1061. Average customer reviews has a small extra line on hover * https://omni-grok.amazon.com/xref/src/appgroup/websiteTempldow.ue) { ue.count("acrStarsLinkWithPopoverClickCount", (ue.count("acrStarsLinkWithPopoverClickC */ .noUnderline a:hover { text-decoration: none; }\n4.2 out of 5 stars 23 ratings P.when(\'A\', \'ready\').execute(function(A) { A.declarativount") || 0) + 1); } }); });\n\n4.2 out of 5 stars\nBest Sellers Rank\n#114,617 in Kitchen & Dinw.ue) { ue.count("acrLinkClickCount", (ue.count("acrLinkClickCount") || 0) + 1); } }); }); P.when(\'A\', \'cf\').execute(function(A) { A.declaing (See Top 100 in Kitchen & Dining)\n#304 in Floor Comfort Mats\n\nDate First Available\nJuly { if(window.ue) { ue.count("acrStarsLinkWithPopoverClickCount", (ue.count("acrStarsLinkWithPopoverClickCount") || 0) + 1); } }); });\n\n4.2 ou
24, 2020\nWarranty & Support\nProduct Warranty: For warranty information about this product, plen#304 in Floor Comfort Mats\n\nDate First Available\nJuly 24, 2020\nWarranty & Support\nProduct Warranty: For warranty information about this ase click here\nFeedback\nWould you like to tell us about a lower price?'}
```

So I was thinking, there has to be a way to target the xpath and return just the value of the ranking or I just need to somehow parse through the whole table and pull out exactly what I need. I would really appreciate if someone could give advice on how to specifically target the ranking or help me come up with a way to parse out the ranking from the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function is designed to work on any ASIN, but a problem I foresee is that Amazon's detail pages are not consistent. The HTML hierarchy of the product's detail section will change depending on the layout.

However, assuming you only care about this specific ASIN (B084BN9PWN) then why don't you just iterate over the # of  tags that hold the best seller rank info you want.

Example:

```
browse_rank_count = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1"]/tbody/tr[6]/td/span/span').getall()
for i in range(len(browse_rank_count)):
    i += 1  # xpath index starts at 1
    browse_rank_string = r.html.xpath('//*[@id="productDetails_detailBullets_sections1"]/tbody/tr[6]/td/span/span[' + str(i) + ']/text()').get()
    print(browse_rank_string)
```

I haven't tested this, so the xpath might be a little off.

I use a paid proxy service called ProxyCrawl which along with the basic proxy service offers an Amazon scraper that does the scraping for you. You just request the data you want for the ASIN. That's an option to consider as well, especially if you're already paying for proxies. Alternatively, you can just map out a series of xpath trys for each detail page variation.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Ive decided to go with ProxyCrawl, very easy to use.